# i need help trying to fix my logic

Tags: python

`multiply_until_total_reached(original,total,n):` Starting with a positive integer original, keep
multiplying original by n and calculate the sum of all multiples generated including original until the
sum is no longer smaller than total. Return the minimum number of multiplications needed to reach at
value at or above the given total.

o Assume: All three arguments are integers: original and n are positive.

o Return value: an integer.

o Examples:

multiply_until_total_reached (1,5,2) → 2

```
# 1*2=2, (1+2)<5, 2*2=4, (1+2+4)>5, 2 multiplications needed
```

multiply_until_total_reached (1,15,2) → 3

```
# 1*2=2, (1+2)<15, 2*2=4, (1+2+4)<15, 4*2=8, (1+2+4+8)=15, 3 multiplications
```

multiply_until_total_reached (1,0,2) → 0

```
# original 1>0, no multiplication
```

for the remaining test cases, im above the actual needed multiplications by 1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlbZK.png)

```
def multiply_until_total_reached(original,total,n):
    zum=original
    add=zum
    count=0

    if original<total:
         while add<total:
            zum=zum*n
            add+=(zum)
            count+=1
    return count

print (multiply_until_total_reached(1,10,1))
```

this giving me correct answers on visualizer but giving me FFFFFFF on command prompt

Comment: Can you provide a sample input, for which you got stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: sorry for this one im not getting an infinite loop, i need to fix my counter.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems with your logic. If we take the first example from your post:

```
# 1*2=2, (1+2)<5, 2*2=4, (1+2+4)>5, 2 multiplications needed
```

**Firstly**, You are comparing the value of `add` to the value of `total`. However, in your while-loop, you are comparing `zum` to `total`. Your condition statement for the while loop is:

```
while zum < total
```

**Secondly**, your logic for adding does not make sense. `add` is sset to zero initially, so why are you doing `(1+2)<5`? It should be `(0+2)<5`. This logic error persists elsewhere in your post.

**Finally**, I ran your code, and I got no infinite loop. Maybe the value that you pass to the function `multiply_until_total_reached(original,total,n)`

---

EDIT: I ran the following block of code on python 3.5.2. It worked fine.

```
def multiply_until_total_reached(original,total,n):
    zum=original
    add=0 
    count=0
    while add<total:
        zum=zum*n
        add+=(zum)
        count+=1
    return count

print (multiply_until_total_reached(1,5,2))
```

Comment: I see that you've replaced  _zum_ with _add_. Just wanted to clarify as my answer was posted before that change, so no downvotes for that reason, please.

Comment: how can i make it all ecompassing? Will i need a double loop for this problem?

Comment: for an input, of 5,5,100 it returns 1 when it should be 0,any ideas?

Comment: Well, when you enter the while loop the first time, (since `add` is initialized to zero before that, which will anyways lead to `add < total` being true the first time), it will add one to counter before checking the condition of the while loop. So, unless `add` is initialized to be greater than `total` __before__ you enter the while loop, count will always be greater than or equal to 1 (`total`, in your question, is always a positive number as you specified, so my answer is based on that given)

Comment: By the way, if my answer works for you, please select the check mark next to my answer, it should turn green when you do so.